# Nodejs sync answer on emit

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I do something like this?

```
var some=function(){
    process.EventEmitter.call(this);
    var answer=this.emit('test');
}
...
var test=some();
test.on('test'){
    return 'answer';
}
```

Maybe exists other feature to messaging between program and module?

Comment: What should it do if there is more than one listener?

Comment: @vkurchatkin only one listener

Comment: than just use functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## It isn't natural for an object to observe itself

From the [Felix's Node.js Style Guide](http://nodeguide.com/style.html#eventemitters). Felix Geisendörfer is an early node.js core contributor.

> I strongly recommend that you never listen to the events of your own class from within it.
>   It isn't natural for an object to observe itself. It often leads to undesirable exposure to 
>   implementation details, and makes your code more difficult to follow.

Node's built-in [EventEmitter](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_events_eventemitter) implementation, specifically its [`#emit` method](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_emit_event_arg1_arg2) documentation, says:

> Execute each of the listeners in order with the supplied arguments.
>
> Returns `true` if event had listeners, `false` otherwise.

So it's not posible to behave as you want inheriting from this implementation (unless you override the `emit` behaviour, of course)

## Reconsider you approach

As @vkurchatkin pointed out on comments, what the behaviour should be if there are more than one listener attached to the emitter?

If you need only one listener, returning something, maybe you should "*extend*" your base "*class*" and override a method with the desired implementation, or modify the desired function on the desired instance, or whatever.

IMHO your aproach is not correct, you should research a bit about and reconsider it.